# Ternary operator is not working scala

Tags: scala, ternary-operator

I'm trying to make a ternary operator in scala but actually it seems that the `'?'` character cannot be resolved

here is the completed method

```
object Credit {
  def getMaximumWeek(orderId: Int, locale: String): Int = {
    val orderCompletedHistoryCount = Order.getOrderCompletedHistoryCount(orderId, locale);
   orderCompletedHistoryCount == 0 ? 0: Order.getMaximumAllowedWeeks(orderId, locale)
  }
}
```

referenced to this [link](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-ternary-operator-syntax)
,**I'm getting an error connot resolve symbol '?'** even both method are returning integers

Comment: The link you posted shows there is no ternary operator in scala and you can just use `if` since it is an expression i.e. `if (orderCompletedHistoryCount == 0) 0 else Order.getMaximumAllowedWeeks(orderId, locale)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Scala does not have a ternary operator*, like the `?` operator C++ has for example, so the error is expected, regardless of what the two operadans return.

Use an if-else expression instead, like this:

```
if(orderCompletedHistoryCount == 0)
    0
else
    Order.getMaximumAllowedWeeks(orderId, locale)
```

Comment: that is strange a bit, is there a way to do it with out if else ?
otherwise it could be like this 

`if(orderCompletedHistoryCount == 0)
    0
    Order.getMaximumAllowedWeeks(orderId, locale)`

Comment: @BasilBattikhi maybe, but not a clean one for sure. You need the else part in the if statement.

Comment: "Use an if-else statement instead, like this:" – There is no `if` statement in Scala. There is only an `if` expression. If `if` were a statement, then you couldn't use it to replace a conditional operator, since the conditional operator is an expression, not a statement. Your answer works *only* because `if` is *not* a statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)** for that. The only difference is it requires `|` sign instead of `:` sign.

```
import scalaz.Scalaz._

false ? "Yes" | "No" // returns No
```

It's not only for booleans, you can try it with `Option` objects as well:

```
None ? "Defined" | "Empty" // returns Empty
```

You should add the following line to build.sbt in order to use it:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.16"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i was wowndering if can i use it without third party

Comment: Unfortunately there is no ternary operator support in the Scala Standard Library. You may write your own or use a library like that.